# MATLAB how to output a matrix in a parfor circulation?

Tags: algorithm, matlab, matrix, parallel-processing

I normally replace the `for` in MATLAB code with `parfor`, but all the 2 dimension matrix did not work.

**Code**

```
parfor k=1 : n
sonic = data1((1+(k-1)*2400):(2400*k));
signal1 = (sonic(1:2400))./100;
Ar = abs(fftshift(fft(signal1,2400)));
[maxb,ind] = max(b);
Tp(k) = 2*pi/x(ind);
E = @(x)(x^2+1);
for i=1:length(x2)
    Ex(i,k) = E(x2(i));
    Exm0(i,k) = Ex(i,k)-m0(k);
    signal2(i) = Exm0(i,k);
end
epsilong(:,k) = Ar; 
end
```

Only variables such as `Tp(k)` appear in the workspace; two dimension matrices like `Ex(i,k)` did not work.

Answer (score 0):

The limitations of FOR loops nested within PARFOR loops are described [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/distcomp/programming-considerations.html#bq__cs7-9) - I think the problem in this case is your loop bounds `1:length(x2)`. As described in that page, you should be able to work around this like so:

```
len_x2 = length(x2);
parfor k = 1:n
    ...
    for i = 1:len_x2
        ...
    end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! Regarding the loop bounds, the matlab document for PARFOR are described [link](http://www.mathworks.cn/cn/help/distcomp/parfor.html), which offers an example as parfor i = 1:length(A)
   B(i) = f(A(i));
end. In order to solve the matrix problem, I think I should define a matrix outside the loop. But problem is how to convey the variable out from a loop.